# What information oscilloscope decodes in the beginning of the waveform binary file?

Tags: binary, decode

## Introduction

I am working with oscilloscope OWON TDS8204. It is possible to save current waveform in binary file with this device. The only information I have now is (seems to be) that data is of 8 bites. So I wrote a simple program to read that binary file and draw the waveform. This is what I get.

[image: Waveform picture]

The first several points is obviously not a part of the waveform. I suspect that this is some additional information. But the question is what information exactly?

## Message

All files contains these bytes in the beginning (hex):

```
5350 4254 3100 4006 0000 0100 0000 0000
0100 0100 0000 0100 0000 0000 0600 0000
0000 a3fb ffff 3433 73c0 9a99 993e 9a99
993e 6f12 833a 5c8f 423f b01d 0000 f205
0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000
```

The first 5 characters are seem to be "SPBT1" but then most of those characters are not printable ASCII bytes.

The original bin file is [here](https://files.fm/u/36fvut7u#_).

Comment: The message is definitely not encrypted...

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark, do not understand. Do you mean like it is not encrypted as a hidden message. If so it is just a figure of speech.

Comment: You are asking what the message is, yes?  You've said "what is the encrypted message?".  It isn't encrypted.  It's just an encoding.